# how can I find the checkbox element in the same td element using its class name

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have two column in a table one with checkbox and another is Input element. I am trying to find the  checkbox element from javascript and to get checked from javascript . Here is my code

```js
var chbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('.nhrs a').empty();
// simillarly I have to find checkbox element and to set its checked property =true
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsProtected" type="hidden" />
        <input type="checkbox" value="true" disabled asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsNormalAttendance" data-tag="NormalHrs" />
        <input type="hidden" value="false" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsNormalAttendance" />
        <input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsClockingEnabled" type="hidden" />
      </td>
      <td class="nhrs">
        <a href="#" class="disabled" data-pk="NormalHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs</a>
        <input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs" type="hidden" class="bros" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not an ASP issue. Please change all ASP in the snippet for RELEVANT RENDERED HTML so we have a [mcve]

Comment: Also tell use from WHERE you need the checkbox: When clicking the link or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("[data-tag=NormalHrs]").prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your checkbox by writing query `.find('input[type="checkbox"]')`