# How can I get the name of the class of the td element in the same row of a table using attribute, from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to  get the name of the classname assigned to the td element in an html table. I have given the class name for two tds and rest of the tds  without class name. If I  click checkbox element,  I want to get the class name of that tds having  data-pk="NormalHrs" attribute only in the same row,

Here is the code

```js
<script>
    $("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
                 var $box = $(this);
                var classname =   $box.parent('td').closest('td.data-pk="NormalHrs"').classname  

    })
</script>
```

```html
   <td class="EditableTd"><a href="#" data-pk="NormalHrs" class="editable editable-click">0.00</a><input type="hidden" class="bros" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NormalHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The NormalHrs field is required." id="attendanceLogList_0__NormalHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].NormalHrs" value="0.00"></td>

 

<td class="holidaycheck"><input type="checkbox" value="true" data-tag="HolidayHrs" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsHolidayMarked field is required." id="attendanceLogList_0__IsHolidayMarked" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsHolidayMarked" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" value="false" id="attendanceLogList_0__IsHolidayMarked" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsHolidayMarked"> </td>
```

***strong text***
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is NOT an ASP Issue. Please change the snippet to have RENDERED HTML and Script ONLY - NO ASP!

Comment: Am I repeating myself here?

Comment: The selector you used in `closest` makes no sense. If you don’t know how attribute selectors work, then why don’t you just go and read up on it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: This is a followup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66255367/how-can-i-find-the-checkbox-element-in-the-same-td-element-using-its-class-name) but incorrectly implemented

Comment: it's [className](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp) not `classname`

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz it's attr("class") in jQuery or [0].className

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the contents of a table row with a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460421/get-the-contents-of-a-table-row-with-a-button-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only know the cell has something with data-pk="NormalHrs" and you need its className, try this

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  const className = $(this).closest('tr').find("[data-pk=NormalHrs]").closest("td").attr("class")
  console.log(className)
})

// OR

$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  const className = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:has(".editable")').attr("class")
  console.log(className)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="EditableTd">
      <a href="#" data-pk="NormalHrs" class="editable editable-click">0.00</a>
      <input type="hidden" class="bros" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NormalHrs must be a number." data-val-required="The NormalHrs field is required." id="attendanceLogList_0__NormalHrs" name="attendanceLogList[0].NormalHrs" value="0.00">
    </td>
    <td class="holidaycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" value="true" data-tag="HolidayHrs" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsHolidayMarked field is required." id="attendanceLogList_0__IsHolidayMarked" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsHolidayMarked" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="hidden" value="false" id="attendanceLogList_0__IsHolidayMarked" name="attendanceLogList[0].IsHolidayMarked"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I given  as you advised me , But it shows different class name.                                             var classname = $(this).closest('tr').find("[data-pk=NormalHrs]").attr("class");

Comment: I repeat my request for the THIRD TIME: Please post a RENDERED PAGE with HTML and tell us EXACTLY what you need the classname of WHICH ELEMENT for when clicking WHICH CHECKBOX!!!

Comment: There are NO TDs with data-pk class like you are asking.., only ONE "A" tag with a DATA ATTRIBUTE of data-pk

Comment: I have given rendered html after running.  the class name is giving 'editable editable-click'. I want to get  EditableTd

Comment: @polachanpaily See update. Why do you need that className?

Comment: I need to provide some condition depends the class name . If class name = 'EditableTd then else another condition. At  the moment after giving the advised command it gives anchor tag class name not closest td class name